# What is the scientific name of this green insect/bug?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

(Picture from Internet)

I want to know the scientific name of this insect. They are very small in size and they do not like to stay at one place so taking pictures is hard. Following are some information which will help in identification.

- Location: India
- Size: Miniscule. About some millimeters
- Color: Green. Sometimes a black dot appears on its wings
- Survive during the post-Monsoon duration i.e. Late July to October. Hence sometimes referred to as Post-Monsoon bugs.
- Attracted to lights. Large number of those swarm around any source of light
- Causes a great deal of damage to crops
- Does not bite but causes local itching on contact with skin
- The name in our native language roughly translates to "green insect" (because of green color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the google search I did,guess they are green leafhoppers.
To find more on the leafhopper of the second half, [this link should help](http://www.knowledgebank.irri.org) .Reach the site and give a search on green leafhoppers in the searchbar.

Well,there are a large no of leafhoppers under the family Cicadellidae and I believe the ones in the picture differ.

If my findings are correct,Cicadella viridis is the scientific name of the leafhopper of the 1st half,the second one comes under *Nephotettix* sp.

Hope it has helped!

Comment: Please take the [tour] and then consult the [help] pages for advice on [Answer] effectively on this site and then [edit] or delete your answer accordingly. In particular: 1) copying content from other sources is [plagiarism](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/628/46609); 2) do not post text as images — images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments; and 3) answers should include supporting references (primary literature is best).

Comment: Please don't post text as images. You can rewrite key points from the source in your own words while *citing* the original source of the information.

Comment: I did some research based on your info and found that indeed they are diffierent typrs of planthoppers/grasshoppers. 1st image is _Cicadella viridis_ which is primarily present in Europe, so let's exclude that. The second one is one of the species under _Nephotettix_ genus. The image I included might be _Nephotettix nigropictus_ or _Nephotettix virescens_, the latter one most likely.

Answer (score 3):

To complete this post, I want to include my answer based on my research which will server as a complementary answer to @BactiPrabha's answer.

---

As @BactiPrabha pointed out, they are "green leaphoppers". There are different types of leaphoppers which implies that the 1st image and 2nd image are not same.

The 1st image is *[Cicadella viridis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicadella_viridis)*. This species is present in most of Europe and in the Indomalayan realm which does not match with my location. So let's exclude that.

The 2nd image is one of the species from *[Nephotettix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nephotettix)* genus and from the characteristics, it could be either *Nephotettix nigropictus* or *Nephotettix virescens*, the latter one most likely. Along with N. cincticeps, they are the most common Asian pest species in this genus and causes diseases like tungro disease in rice. Hence they are also called "Pest of Paddy".

For more information, go through these links:

1. https://www.cabi.org/isc/datasheet/36200
2. https://agritech.tnau.ac.in/crop_protection/rice/crop_prot_crop_insectpest%20_cereals_paddy_2.html